# Admin Subpages without Menu entry

Tags: plugin-development, wp-admin

I have added some pages to the WP-Adminmenu, with `add_menu_page` and `add_submenu_page`. The URLs for those pages look like `admin.php?page=my-plugin/admin/submenupage.php`. If I try to add a page now that has isnt registered to the menu and link to it with `<a href="?page=my-plugin/admin/add.php">` I'm getting a permissions error. Is there a way to add pages to the admin area without registering them to the menu?

Comment: Please always show your whole code.

Comment: @kaiser do you miss anything? I think in this case the whole code would be more annoying since its distributed over some classes etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing you can do here is to call them with a `$_GET` parameter, and just register the first site to the menu.

so for example, when you registered `admin.php?page=my-plugin/admin/submenupage.php`, you have the `submenupage.php` structured like this:

```
if ( !isset( $_GET['section'] ) ) {
     include('mainpage.php');
} else if ($_GET['section'] == 'hiddenpage1' ){
     include('mainpage.php');
} // go on for every page needed.
```

This way you have your registered menuentry, but by clicking it from the adminmenu you always get to the `mainpage.php`.
Just add the `&section=hiddenpage1` or whatever you call your hidden pages, and you will see the "hidden" admin sections.